# How to get user info ussing google access token

Tags: json, rest, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, access-token

Hi i am developing a google oauth2 login and i dont't know how to get a user info using **access** token or **id** token using this urls

- https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo passsing access token in Authorization header returns this json:

```
    "sub": "100366573866312827626",
    "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/default-user=s96-c"
}
```

- [https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token={id_token}](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=%7Bid_token%7D) get this json

```
{
    "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
    "azp": "375890336523-u4rpach5688ltoc0v4mof1r7j70gem95.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "aud": "375890336523-u4rpach5688ltoc0v4mof1r7j70gem95.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "sub": "100366573866312827626",
    "at_hash": "htkn2tQqV4Ff4EmrtPDh9w",
    "iat": "1636631006",
    "exp": "1636634606",
    "alg": "RS256",
    "kid": "27c72619d0935a290c41c3f010167138685f7e53",
    "typ": "JWT"
}
```

But in both json doesn't have any user information like username or email

thanks for your time and sorry for my english, is not my native languaje

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you authorized the user that you requested profile scope.

Using the Access token returned when your user authorized your application. You can get  the users profile information you should make a call to the [People.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) method

```
curl \
  'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

The user info endpoint will give you a little bit of info but not as much as using the userinfo endpoint.

Google does not always return the user claims in the id token, so i would not try to rely upon that.

Comment: Hi, i dont't have a lot of knowledge of oauth, how i get the profile scope, and whe you said YOUR_API_KEY it means my client_id?

Comment: Now i am get the full name and emial but in 2 request, put the scope profile and emal en each, it is possible get all info in only 1 request?